# Dual Monitor not working

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, intel-graphics

I have a **MSI Z87-G43** motherboard with **i5-4670K** CPU. When I connect two monitors to the onboard graphic card (1xVGA and 1xDVI) both screens are black, there seems to be a connection when the pc is turned on (i.e it says "DVI, or VGA") but nothing actually shows.

If I only connect one of them then it all works fine. If I connect a second screen while in Windows 8 the computer will hang (no ctrl+alt-del, no nothing).

The graphics drivers and BIOS are updated.

Comment: Do you also have a dedicated graphics card?

Comment: not currently connected, if that's what you are asking

Comment: however I did try with a "regular" pci graphic card and both screens worked fine

Comment: Does it matter which monitor is being used when the second monitor is plugged in? Does both combinations result in Windows locking up? This really does sound like a driver problem. What operating system?  You have the current BIOS firwmare revision?

Comment: No difference at all, tried different combination and it Windows  will lock up

Comment: The reason why I ask is because there may be a setting in your BIOS that specifies whether you want to use on-board or dedicated graphics.

Comment: @yassarikhan786 oh, well I tried with default settings and also changed to dual screen settings but to no avail

Comment: Do you not have a "Primary Graphics Adapter" option anywhere in your BIOS?

Comment: @yassarikhan786 yes and it is set on IGD (onboard graphics)

Comment: That's strange. Did you update the BIOS because you had the same issue with an older BIOS version?

Comment: @Mechk - What version of Windows are we talking about exactly?  Still waiting to know the revision of the BIOS there was a July update released by MSI.

Comment: @yassarikhan786 no the BIOS was updated (since the mobo is new)

Comment: @Mechk - It being new does not mean it has the current revision.

Comment: @Ramhound I have checked the versions and it is indeed up to date

Comment: @Mechk - Still waiting to confirm your using either Windows 7 or Windows 8.  This could simply be a motherboard hardware issue because your CPU has the ability to support 3 displays.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 8

Comment: @Mechk - This crash even happen without the Intel HD4000 graphics driver?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, it happened before I updated the driver

Comment: Before you updated or installed the drivers in either even I would contact MSI for an RMA if this was me

Comment: Have you tried other combinations, like HDMI-DVI etc.?

Comment: @happy_soil When I try the HDMI combined with DVI/VGA the computer doesn't hang but nothing shows on the HDMI monitor

Comment: Very strange indeed. The manual for your motherboard explicitly says it's multi-monitor capable. Have you tried booting into another OS, say Windows 7? If not, do a fresh install but only use a single display until you've installed all the drivers and Windows updates. After that you can start hooking up additional monitors.